# What's the best way to init data for Java Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I am currently working on creating simple Rest API application with using Spring Boot. The topic that makes me think is data presentation. Last time when I was doing it (maybe two years ago) basing on Github API I've used  low level mechanisms( reading data from Github API URI and streaming it with using `BufferedReader` onto string, which I have transformed with `ObjectMapper`. Although I can just add static data like using `list.add()`, I'm wondering what's the best way to make it happen.

Looking forward to hear!

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Clarify what you need to do.

Comment: What is "best"? Fastest? Easiest? Most secure? Shortest code? Quickest to write? Simplest to deploy? With data streams or old-school synchronous http?

Comment: Okay, so to be more clear:

Let's say that I want to create rest server. This app contains one GET method and returns list of Github repository. When I made that kind of solution, I had a reference of Github API with prepared endpoints that returned it for me. I thought that read content from URL page that contained specified API endpoint with transforming that content with some tricky solutions like ObjectMapper would be good. Now, I think that there should be some other way to get data

Answer (score 1):

With JSR-311 support of RESTful services was added to JavaEE. Also known as project Jersey, you can find many resources for that in the internet, e.g. at Oracle where you can find tutorials how to set up a RESTful service on the [server side](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html) or how you can access resources [as a client](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html).

Comment: @wmk Please be more specific. What do you want to achieve, what is the concrete scenario, what are you doing with the fetched data?

Comment: Okay, so:

I want to create rest server. App contains GET method and returns let's say list of Github repositories. As I have been doing it before, I had a reference of Github API with prepared endpoint that returns specified repositories. When I did that rest server some time ago, I have made it in way that my controller launched URI, read whole data from page (it was just a JSON) and then parse with ObjectMapper to object. Although I see nothing wrong with such low level solutions, I'm wondering how could I made it in another way.

Comment: @wmk Follow the link I provided for a tutorial for the server side. All "relevant" Java based HTTP-servers (e.g. Jetty, Tomc@t) support the annotations you use in these classes, so you can simply drop a war-file containing your classes and the whole thing will be available as REST service.